# My Numeric Keyboard is not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, intellij-idea

I am working on Idea intellij. I am using command in xml `Andriod:inputtype="phone"` But when my emulator run it will not show soft keyboard

Kindly please help me to sort out this problem

```
my xml code is this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myPic">
<EditText

        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"

/>
```

and my java code is this

```
package com.example.api19;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    View context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        EditText editText = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput((editText), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EditText editText = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Please tell me the solution of this error
[image]

In this image only the key of AVD work. It is not showing keyboard from bottom side of the screen
The soft numeric keyboard is not showing when edit on text field

Comment: soft Keyboard open for other text ?

Comment: The command I am using will appear a numeric keyboard on screen. but mine emulator doesn't show it. I have also pasted a picture with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this happens. But when I unchecked "Hardware keyboard present" for my device, in the AVD manager provided with android SDK, I was able to see soft keyboard.

Thanks.

[![When I un check it my keyboard appear
And when I check it my keyboard does not appear ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcRBx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcRBx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Write `inputType="number"`

```
<EditText

    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"

/>
```

Comment: I also write number in it but the error is same as it is.

Comment: editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); Remove it

Comment: Same error. My keys work, but numeric keyboard is still not showing

Comment: try to run it on actual device instead of emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AVD and enable the keyboard option from it. In android studio go to Tools-> Android-> AVD MAnager -> Select Edit option from right side -> View Device Configuration Dialog -> Select Advance Settings -> Check Enable keyboard input

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My keys are working fine but numeric keyboard is not showing on screen when I click on edit text field

Comment: I also attached the picture with code of my emulator. Numeric keyboard on screen is not showing

Comment: Please edit your avd and enable it from settings using above screenshot